# PHP Color Manipulation

Tags: php, colors, gdlib

I am currently looking into color manipulation / selection etc and have come across the following piece of code. I was wondering of someone could tell me what the following piece of code is doing and break it down for me thanks!

```
$newVal = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33);
```

In particluar what is the 0x33

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be converting `$rgb['red']` the nearest multiple of 0x33.

It's probably doing that so the color will end up on the so-called "web safe" color palette, which (if I recall correctly) consists of colors who's rgb values are multiples of 0x33.

0x33 is the base-16 (hex) representation of 51 (decimal).

Answer (score 1):

0x33 is 51, so it scales the 0-255 value of a single byte to 0-5, and then scales it back out. This results in the value being floored to the highest multiple of 51 lower than the value.

Answer (score 0):

0x33 is just hex value for 33.

I'm not really sure what is happening, but my guess would be it calculates a web safe hex of any color. Or something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

As @Seth indicated, it's rounding colours to the nearest 'web-safe' colour. It's an old idea, dating from back when most colour displays were 8-bit. One of the people to make it popular was Visibone as their 'websafe colour chart' was their first product.

See [Web Colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colours) for more information.